# is there a way to create symbolic link with wildcard

Tags: bash, symlink

I have a script run.sh to which i created a number of symlinks like pf1, pf2 etc.

I want anything which starts with pf to map to this. Is there a way for me to create a symbolic link with a wildcard like "pf*" so that i don't have to create symbolic links for pf11, pf12 etc in the future?

Comment: You could create cron to automatically build the symlinks for you. But you hard to make a recommendation without knowing the context. Why do you want all these symlinks?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are all the symlinks to the same file? Or to different files with the same name as each respective link, but in a different directory?

Comment: @Wes. Why cron? Why not just update the process to make the link properly?

Comment: Post some specific examples and actual code please

Comment: All the links point to the same file. As an example, when pf1 is run, the script (run.sh) will get the base path and identify it is pf1 and run some function

Comment: @MadPhysicist Cron if he has a growing list of files (p23,p24) but it actually sounds like he should be sending an argument to the "run.sh p23" - Not sure what process is happening "in the future" :)

Comment: _"All the links point to the same file."_  In that case: `for i in {1..1000}; do ln -s ./run.sh ./pf$i; done`

Comment: You may also want to look at https://superuser.com/questions/633605/how-to-create-symbolic-links-to-all-files-class-of-files-in-a-directory and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46047/create-symbolic-links-with-wildcards.

Answer (score 7):

In case bash is supported on your system (which is the case in most systems), you could do something like this -

```
bash -c "ln -s sourcedir/pf* targetdir/"
```

Comment: Just adding this here. If the source directory doesnt exists, this will add '*' as a broken symlink.

Answer (score 5):

No. Symbolic link resolution is handled by the kernel whereas globbing is shell-specific.

If you store `pf*` in a symlink, the kernel will look for a file literally named `pf*`. You could theoretically `readlink` that and have your shell expand the read pattern, but then you might as well store the pattern in a regular file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create symbolic links, which are broken (and become fully working, once the file is there), but a `*` wildcard will not be expanded before the files are there. Other expansions will work. Check it yourself using `echo`:

```
$ echo asdf*
asdf*
```

The wildcard is not expanded here, but you can use

```
$ echo asdf{1,2,3}
asdf1 asdf2 asdf3
```

and it is expanded as you would expect it.