# How to create a symlink using ansible.builtin.file with wildcard in src path?

Tags: linux, ansible, symlink

I'm trying code

```
    - name: create a symlink
      ansible.builtin.file:
        src: /usr/share/easy-rsa/*
        dest: ~/easy-rsa/
        state: link
```

but getting err `Error while replacing: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'/usr/share/easy-rsa/*'`

Is it possible to create a symlink with `ansible.builtin.file` using wildcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Is it possible to create a symlink with `ansible.builtin.file` using wildcard?***

In short,

> *No. Symbolic link resolution is handled by the kernel whereas globbing is shell-specific.*<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121197/6771046)</sup>

> *No, that is not how file systems work. A file system stores existing file names, not potential file names.*<sup>[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686094/266568)</sup>

If using `shell` module with Bash [you could do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813555/6771046).

The long answer would be to check the existence of directories and [create the symlinks within a loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46056/266568). For this a few tasks will be necessary.

**Credits To**

- [Is there a way to create symbolic link with wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121197/6771046)
- [Create symlinks with wildcard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/686094/266568)
- [Create symbolic links with wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46056/266568)

and many more ...

- [Create symbolic links to files using wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/)